# Set of bounded linear operators $\mathcal{L}(X, Y)$ between infinite-dimensional normed spaces is not baire

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-theory

I have the following problem

*Let* $X$ *and* $Y$ *be infinite-dimensional normed spaces. Can the space* $\mathcal{L}(X, Y)$ *of all bounded linear operators between X and Y not be baire?*

I know, that we an inclusion $\mathcal{L}(X, Y)\hookrightarrow \mathcal{L}(X, \bar{Y})$, where $\bar{Y}$ is a completion of $Y$, and $\mathcal{L}(X, \bar{Y})$ is a banach space since $\bar{Y}$ is banach. But I have no idea how $\mathcal{L}(X, Y)$ can look like there.

Maybe there are examples that $\mathcal{L}(X, Y)$ is a set of the first category or examples of interesting spaces $\mathcal{L}(X, Y)$ within the framework of the Baire category theorem?

Comment: What does linearity mean for functions between metric spaces? And what does dimension mean?

Comment: Sorry, I meant normed spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = Y = c_0^0$ - space of all sequences of real numbers that have only finite number of non-zero terms with $\sup$-norm: $\|x\| = \max_i |x_i|$. Let $e^i$ be sequence $i$-th term of which is $1$ and rest are $0$.

Let $L_k$ be subset of $\mathcal{L}(X, Y)$ s.t. for all $A \in L_k$, $n \geq k$, $(Ae^1)_n = 0$.

Then $L_k$ is closed: if $A \notin L_k$, then for some $n \geq k$ we have $|(Ae^1)_n| > \varepsilon$, and thus distance between $A$ and $L_k$ is at least $\varepsilon$.

$L_k$ has empty interior: if $A \in L_k$, $B_n$ is s.t. $B_n e^1 = \frac{e_k}{n}$, $B_n e^i = 0$ if $i > 1$ then $A + B_n \to A$ but $A + B_n \notin L_k$.

Also $\mathcal{L}(X, Y) = \cup_k L_k$, because if $A \in \mathcal{L}(X, Y)$ then $Ae^1$ has finite number of non-zero terms.

Thus, $\mathcal{L}(X, Y)$ is countable union of closed nowhere dense sets, and so not Baire.